# Create comma separated string from 2 lists the groovy way

Tags: groovy

What I have so far is:

```
def imageColumns = ["products_image", "procuts_subimage1", "products_subimage2", "prodcuts_subimage3", "products_subimage4"]    
def imageValues = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]
def imageColumnsValues = []

// only care for columns with values
imageValues.eachWithIndex { image,i ->
  imageColumnsValues <<  "${imageColumns[i]} = '${image}'"
}

println  imageColumnValuePair.join(", ")
```

It works but I think it could be better. Wish there was a collectWithIndex ... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no collectWithIndex, but you can achieve the same result with a little effort:

```
def imageColumns = ["products_image", "procuts_subimage1", "products_subimage2", "prodcuts_subimage3", "products_subimage4"]
def imageValues = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]

def imageColumnsValues = [imageValues, 0..<imageValues.size()].transpose().collect { image, i ->
    "${imageColumns[i]} = '${image}'"
}

println imageColumnsValues.join(", ")
```

This takes the list of items and a range of numbers from 0 size(list) - 1, and zips them together with `transpose`.  Then you can just collect over that result.

Comment: I like transpose()! There is no need for the range then, simply:

def imageColumnsValues = [imageValues,imageColumns].transpose().collect { value, column ->
    "${value} = '${column}'"
}

will do. Thanks!